# How to read contents of "contacts2.db" file from the phone programmatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is it possible to read the database files in Android 2.1 ? For example, files in /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/ contacts2.db. If yes, how? And is it possible to replace this file programmatically in order to import / export contacts or any other database files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would never access

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

EVER. You can't read that file from your app without root access anyways. What your looking for is content providers. As the URI specifies that is a provider to the contacts database. You want to look more into Content Providers and specifically in your case the Contact Provider. You can look at the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Brosa- Thank you for this solution...
But I just wanted to know that, is there any event gets fired when any application tries to use the contacts..?? Can you help me out for this problem??

Comment: When you are dealing with content providers there is such thing called content observers which do as it sounds they observe the underlying provider for changes. Look at Content Observers on the Android Developer Website.